# Object oriented pattern in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, inheritance

I am a complete beginner in Flutter and Dart and need help.
I have two StatefulWidget classes their associated State classes:

```dart
class **ManPage** extends StatefulWidget {
  // Class implementation
}
class _ManPageState extends State<ManPage> {
  // State class implementation
}

class WomanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // Class implementation
}
class _WomanPageState extends State<WomanPage> {
  // State class implementation
}
```

A lot of code is duplicated in these two classes such as getting information from a server and presenting it. And code is also duplicated in ManPage and WomanPage.

Then I tried to make ManPage and WomanPage inherit from PersonPage.

I first create a _PersonState hoping it could contain all the common code of _ManPageState and _WomanPageState but I do not see how to use it into _ManPageState and _WomanPageState.

What is the good pattern to do that?

Could composition solve my problem better than inheritance?

Any sugestion will be most helpfull.

Comment: you should provide some code example to clarify what exactly you are trying to achive and how you doing it.

Comment: You can use mixin on T extends StatefulWidget to add methods to your widget class, and a similar mixin on State<T extends StatefulWidget> to add methods to your state classes.  You can put all the common code in those two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **[use generics](https://dart.dev/language/generics)** for that. You can have a custom widget which extends `StatefulWidget` and its corresponding state class extend `State` restricted to that previously defined widget. For example:

```dart
abstract class PersonStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonStatefulWidget({Key? key, required this.name}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String name;
}

abstract class _PersonWidgetState<T extends PersonStatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  Widget buildSomeWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
  
  void doSomethingOnTap() {
    // Do something
  }
}

class ManPage extends PersonStatefulWidget {
  const ManPage({super.key, required super.name});

  @override
  State<ManPage> createState() => _ManPageState();
}

class _ManPageState extends _PersonWidgetState<ManPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

If you only want to share common methods or behaviors, you could also use [mixin](https://dart.dev/language/mixins)'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are checking how to implement it in our project and we come back to you.

Comment: Thanks pcba-dev! We managed to use your pattern.